# Can I get a list of users that requested to follow me in my Instagram private account?

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api

I'm using [instabot](https://github.com/instagrambot/instabot/) in python.

I want to get a list of users that requested to follow me and accept some of them according to some conditions and stuff.
I have read the documentation and didn't find anything about this.

I just want to have the list somehow.
Not just through instabot.
So if u know another way to get the list, some kind of web scraping or by using another bot or even Instagram's native API, I will be happy to hear (read!) that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Instabot in Python, but you can use this as a reference https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API.

That library is written in PHP and able to do get your pending follower list, even to do actions such as reject or accept the follow request. I'm currently using that library and it's well maintained.

Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Install following library:

https://github.com/instagrambot/instabot

And use `get_pending_follow_requests` function to retrieve intended list.